# Dart/Flutter Typeahead for JSON API with indexed list

Tags: flutter, api, dart

Can someone give me an example of how to use the typeahead to autofill a search field
and put it in the URL /$typedata/ where it calls an API and returns a JSON file that looks like the below?  All of the examples I see are nice and neat with the booktitle: "Leaving";
author: "whoever";
publisher: "Phantom";

or there is a list with the variables already identified ["Leaving", "whoever", "Phantom"]

I can't figure out how to put all of these elements together.  I need to extract the "compound: []
up to six variables.
It's several different pieces and I'm new.  I can't seem to get past the compound with mutliple variables.  I know I need an index and to call the index by number but I can't seem to get it all together.
Any help is appreciated.

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 0
    },
    "total": 6,
    "dictionary_terms": {
        "compound": [
            "aspirin",
            "Aspirina",
            "AspirinTest2",
            "ASPIRIN (MART.)",
            "ASPIRIN COMPONENT OF AXOTAL",
            "ASPIRIN COMPONENT OF AZDONE"
        ]
    }
}
```

btw: I'm new to this and I'm sure I'm missing something important. Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead which gives you the opportunity to supply an async function to fetch suggestions - typically from the backend. Its first example shows exactly this: `await BackendService.getSuggestions(pattern)`

Comment: Even though the package is misnamed "typeahead", that's actually "autocomplete".  It's too late to change the package name, but at least they include a disclaimer in the docs as I recall.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  You've confirmed I am doing it correctly.  The Error I'm getting is a Type Error which I haven't been able to fix.  Error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'.  I can't add my code.  I guess I need to create a different question.